# building TestFlightSDK with cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoapods, testflight

I seem to be getting the error message while trying to compile TestFlightSDK in my app via cocoapods

Im my Podfile i have the line:

```
pod 'TestFlightSDK'
```

And the pod update works fine.

When i try and compile the app i get the message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TestFlight", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in OurDealAppDelegate_iPhone.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

my app is only supporting Architecture armv7 (because if i add armv7s or arm64 older libraries fail to compile - so i assume its something to do with this.

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you need to confirm whether `Cocoapods` has included `libTestFlight.a` library in your project. `Cocoapods` has never added the library for me.

So, please follow the steps below:

- Open the Pods-TestFlightSDK target in the Pods.xcodeproj project
- Open Build Phases tab and add `libTestFlight.a`

`libTestFlight.a` can be found at `[$SRCROOT]/Pods/TestFlightsSDK`

Comment: this worked but can you explain to me why i have to do this? cocoapods should be doing this itself and i shouldnt have to manually do this for libraries that i add via cocoapods

Comment: Yes, you are correct, `cocoapods` should do it for us but for some reasons it doesn't. This is why I add it manually without using `cocoapods`.